# Model fitting with Chinese Restaurant Process

Tags: clustering, cross-validation, nonparametric, hyperparameter, expectation-maximization

I am trying cluster a trajectory, consisting of (state, action) sequences, by assigning them to the most likely model that generated them using Chinese Restaurant Process. Basically my goal is to infer $\rho_{ij}$, which represents the probability that $i^{th}$ trajectory was generated by $model\ j$ and learn parameters $\theta_j$ associated with each model.

I am using an approximate inference with online Expectation Maximization (without refining previous assignments when new trajectories arrive) to compute   $\rho_{ij}$ for each trajectory and model using a Chinese Restuarant Prior. I have basically two queries here:

1. I have two models $M_1$ and $M_2$ where the models have parameters $\theta$ learned by EM and also a set of hyperparameters. Can the hyperparameters be tuned by doing a cross-validation by computing marginal likelihood of trajectories on the test dataset ?
2. $M_1$ and $M_2$ have different numbers of hyperparameters, so if they are learned from the dataset, do we need to penalize the likelihood used in computing posterior probability  $\rho_{ij} \propto likelihood(trajectory\ i ,model\ j) * prior(model\ j)$